# Python OOP tracing small confusion

Tags: python, oop

```
class GrandParent():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def blah(self):
        return "GP:" + self._a + self._b

class Parent2(GrandParent):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self._a = b
        self._b = a
        self._c = self.blah()

class Child2(Parent2):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):    
        Parent2.__init__(self, a, b, c)

    def blah(self):
        return ("C2: " + self._a + self._b
        + self._c + self._d)


c2 = Child2("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

Here is the code I am supposed to trace. I create an object `c2` of `Child2`. I go in `Child2.__init__`. I go in `Parent2.__init__`. I initialize `self._a`, `self._b`.

My problem is with `self._c`.

`Parent2` does not have a `blah()` method, so I would expect it to get `self._c` from `GrandParent.blah()`, but instead it goes to the `Child2.blah()`. Why does this occur?

Comment: In your example `Child2` needs to be a subclass of `Parent2` (it currently says `Parent1`).  The edit is too small for me to fix it.

Comment: @P-robot done, there were several other improvements that could be made so the edit was big enough.

Comment: Actually this is a code snippet part of something bigger, but the Parent1 did not play a factor, neither did classes like Child1, so I removed them because they weren't relevant to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `self` is a direct instance of `Child2` so `self.blah()` must be the equivalent of `Child2.blah(self)`. That the code happens to be in a method of a parent of `Child2` just before that call is not relevant.

Comment: Ohhhh .... but in the case that Child2 did not ahve blah , then would it call the parent?

Comment: Yes. More specifically it will look through `Child2.__mro__` (method resolution order) and pick the first one that has the method.